# Prestashop - when editing the customer's address in the order, the shipping price will change to zero, but it should remain

Tags: prestashop

Prestashop: 1.7.4
I found a bug in BO-Orders: If an address of a customer is edited directly in the order, the shipping cost in this order is changed to zero. The shipping cost should remains, not reset. If I edit the same address directly in BO-Customers, the shipping cost will not change.

Can you please help me, how solve this bug? I can edit any file directly in the code.

Comment: Update Prestashop to 1.7.8 or 8.0, this was a well-known bug of earlier 1.7 version.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't upgrade, we have a lot of custom mods. I tried to find this bug described somewhere to fix the error myself, but I couldn't find anything. Can I ask for a link or help where to edit a file?

Answer (score 1):

Shop parameters -> Order settings -> Recalculate shipping costs after editing the order - set to "No".

If you still think it's bug, consider checking if it happens on the newest PrestaShop version. 1.7.4 is quite old.

Comment: You are great, thank you very much, your answer is very helpfull and solved this problem.